# Ubuntu 17.04 - Where is file /etc/default/rcS?

Tags: 17.04, time

I'm trying to fix a date&time problem in my Ubuntu 17.04 but I cant't find mentioned file `/etc/default/rcS`. I find only this path `/etc/rcS.d` but I think it has nothing to do with UTC default setting.
I'm looking for option `UTC=yes/no`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04+ is using `systemd`. To set your time to local run

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

The `/etc/default/rcS` is for older Ubuntu releases that use `upstart`.

Comment: Yes, it's what I was looking for.