# My xubuntu partition of my surface go dual boot boots into command line

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, refind, surface

I have Windows 10 and Xubuntu linux installed on my surface go. I also use rEFInd boot manager. After some time (days, weeks, etc), my Xubuntu partition stops loading its GUI. I'll just boot into command line. I've actually reinstalled ubuntu on this machine to "fix" this issue but its basically just a bandaid solution. The issue just reappears overtime. My suspicion is that it has something to do windows and how my computer boots, however, I've never had this issue on my laptop nor desktop.

I'm wondering what is going on. It seems to happen regardless of what version of ubuntu I use. I'll get the following message:

```
Error message:
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: Superblock last mount time is in the future (by less than a day, probably due to hardware clock being incorrectly set)
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 233072/1831424 files, 2190469/7324160 blocks
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "system ctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot  into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or Control-D to continue)
```

journalctl -xb does give me a log but its super long and I am not sure what information is pertinent.

I've tried running fsck but the commandline complains that the drive it is running on is mounted.

Comment: Disabling Fast Startup in Windows is always recommended. In dual-boot it's a must.

Comment: It was enabled. I disabled it, used shut down and rebooted into linux but the problem persisted. I tried it a few times just to be sure.

Comment: Have you tried booting with a live USB, mounting the drive and running `fsck` on it? Also posting the contents of `journalctl` could prove helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause:
Windows and Linux do not interpret System time the same way (UTC vs. local time).
If this is the case, possible solutions consist of having both OSs interpret the system time the same way, either UTC or local time [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot).

Possible solutions:

1. Set Windows to UTC, see "Make Windows use UTC" [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/169384/226614).

   *Please post in your question the exact location of file `WindowsTimeFixUTC.reg` in Windows. Then post in your question the exact contents of that file.*
2. Set Ubuntu to Local time, see "Make Linux use 'Local' time" [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/169384/226614):
   `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` (you [may need to add](https://askubuntu.com/a/944947/226614) `--adjust-system-clock`).

   *Please post in your question the exact output of*

   ```
   $ timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
   $ timedatectl
   ```
3. If `hwclock` gives you trouble, you might need [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/852008/326962).

   *Please post in your question the exact output of*

   ```
   $ hwclock --verbose
   ```
4. Possibly not applicable, since it is for old Ubuntus. Edit `/etc/default/rcS`, change `UTC=no` to `UTC=yes`. Create the file if needed ([source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/rcS.5.html)). You can also add another line with `VERBOSE=yes`.
5. Idem. Edit `/etc/default/rcS`, change `FSCKFIX=no` to `FSCKFIX=yes` (perhaps a last resource).
6. Verify that power to the internal clock is provided normally. As the Surface Go does not seem to have a CMOS battery, I am not sure about checking/fixing this.
   https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/153800/CMOS+backup+battery+inside+Surface

**Sources / Related**:

8. https://serverfault.com/a/71625/326962 and other options in the same question
9. [Ubuntu 17.04 - Where is file /etc/default/rcS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944946/ubuntu-17-04-where-is-file-etc-default-rcs)
10. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2433546

Comment: Number 1 didn't work. I'm not seeing an rcS file in the /etc/default directory. If I try nanoing into it, I get a blank file.

Comment: Number 2 gives me an error `Failed to create bus connection: no  such file or directory`

Comment: I have added information in items 1-3 that you would post in your question for a clearer picture.
Note, as an example, that [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280075/how-to-permanently-open-browsers-in-firejail) could only be solved after several iteration of asking exact information, and it was the only way to see the problem. 
I suggest you do not see the 3 minutes it takes you to post as a burden, but rather a possible solution.